# MySQL Join assistance

Tags: mysql, database

[image: img]

Hey guys I am struggling to create a query which gives schedule of a pilot for a given day. So far I've got

```
SELECT f.flight_date, l.lesson_date FROM Flight f JOIN lesson l ON f.pilot_idpilot = l.pilot_idpilot WHERE f.flight_date = CURDATE() OR l.lesson_date = CURDATE() AND pilot_idpilot = 7236;
```

The result I get is

```
Lesson_id | lesson_date | pilot_idpilot | idFlight | flight_date | pilot_id_pilot
```

Is there a way just to specify the type of activity the pilot is involved in e.g.

```
Activity | Date |
```

Any help would be awesome! thanks guys/girls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 'Lesson' as Activity, lesson_date as Date
FROM Flight f JOIN lesson l ON f.pilot_idpilot = l.pilot_idpilot 
WHERE l.lesson_date = CURDATE() AND pilot_idpilot = 7236
UNION
SELECT 'Flight' as Activity, flight_date as Date
FROM Flight 
WHERE f.flight_date = CURDATE() AND pilot_idpilot = 7236;
```